Ideal system architecture for sensitive data access through DMZ
I'm trying to figure out the best approach for handling external requests. I am working on a system where the application is currently sitting outside (DMZ) and the DB is inside. The specific port required for DB access has been opened from DMZ machine to DB machine.
After discussing with my team, we have agreed that DMZ shouldn't be connecting to the DB directly. After further discussion, we have shortlisted the following two approaches as possible solutions.
To me, both seem to be the same as far as security is concerned since we have the same communication protocols being used and the same number of layers.
Is my understanding correct? If so, would B be the more logical option? A would mean that we have a custom data access service which handles requests from the APP and reads/writes data.
Finally, if we do go with B, would it be recommended that we still use the Data Access Service but it would be internal (i.e. APP -> Data Access Service -> DB)


If you didn't incorporate security considerations when designing and implementing application logic early on, then you're doomed. WAF can only provide generic protection.

The principle is that the DMZ is less secure than inside. One risk to consider is that a server in the DMZ can get compromised.
In such a scenario, the attacker can use that server for lateral moves to other devices or services in the DMZ. For example a weaker server in the dmz could be used to gain control of your app server in scenario A. The attacker could also  deepen the attack by moving from your app server to the database.
Compromised devices
can no longer be trusted, since the attacker could gain total control and know everything that the  device knows. For example it could misuse the accessible db port and send its own db commands either to corrupt your db, exfiltrate valuable data or worse, encrypt your data or exploit vulnerabilities of your db engine to move inside.
The logical consequence is that the app should be behind the dmz, since you can control much more what comes in. The reverse proxy are designed for security and are more difficult to control. And your app would manage the session, enforce authorisations and make sure db remains accessed following the expected rules.
Other scenarios could also be considered, with an extra layer in the dmz.
